# Timer start is not allowing my other pages to load when using Navigate.Push in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, countdowntimer

I used the `System.Timers.Timer();` code to do the count down Timer on page load and then I used the `Navigate.Push` to go into another page.

Timer Code on page load:

```cs
public Index()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    StartCountDownTimer();
}

DateTime endTime = new DateTime(2019, 08, 25, 14, 00, 0);
public void StartCountDownTimer()
{
    try
    {
        timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Elapsed += t_Tick;
        TimeSpan ts = endTime - DateTime.Now;        
        lblCountDown.Text = ts.ToString("d' Days 'h' Hours 'm' Minutes 's' Seconds'");
        timer.Start();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string Error = ex.Message;
    }
}


System.Timers.Timer timer;
void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        TimeSpan ts = endTime - DateTime.Now;
        string NewTimer = ts.ToString("d' Days 'h' Hours 'm' Minutes 's' Seconds'");
        //txtCountDown.Text = NewTimer;
        lblCountDown.Text = NewTimer;
        if ((ts.TotalMilliseconds < 0) || (ts.TotalMilliseconds < 1000))
        {
            timer.Stop();
            lblCountDown.Text = "The day has arrived";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string Error = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Navigate Code using a button click on the same page:

```cs
private void ClickAboutTab(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page());

        }
```

Code of page I am navigating to:

```cs
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="AppName.Pages.Page">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Solutions I already tried before navigating are:

```cs
timer.Stop();
timer.Dispose();
timer = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

The timer callback is not invoked from the UI thread.

You need to invoke all ui related stuff from the ui thread:

```cs
void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        TimeSpan ts = endTime - DateTime.Now;
        string countDownValue = ts.ToString("'d' Days 'h' Hours 'm' Minutes 's' Seconds");

        if ((ts.TotalMilliseconds < 0) || (ts.TotalMilliseconds < 1000))
        {
            timer.Stop();
            countDownValue = "The day has arrived";
        }

        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
            lblCountDown.Text = countDownValue;
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string Error = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Roubachof, thanks for the reply but even when I add the above code, it does not display the content of the page I am Navigating to but as soon as I comment the Count down timer code out, then I am able to Navigate to any page successfully.

Comment: Please edit your question and add all the code from this page.

Comment: I have updated my comment. Must I add the code of the page that I am navigating to, because even if its a blank page with a label, it wont display that label, as mentioned above?

Comment: First, you didn't post the whole page. Second, what is the issue exactly? Is it not navigating? Or is it navigating but the page is blank? If it's the second option, you must also post the whole page you want to navigate to.

Comment: It is option 2, please find the updated code above.

Comment: come on... post the WHOLE code of your page, you're only selecting portions, we need ALL of it.

Comment: There you go, I added every single part of my code. What more do you need to start assisting me?

Comment: Add everything I have given you above in a blank Xamarin project and you will see the issue I am facing......

Comment: My problem is: Page is blank when I navigate to it. It is not to make the timer still run, just to clarify my issue as I see it is being confused.